# How to add rows of 3D cell

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, cell-array

I have 3-D (60x72x29) cell arrays with numbers inside, and I want to add the rows across the 3rd dimension so that the resulting cell size should be (60x72). Is there any elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elegant way is to not use a cell array to hold multi-dimensional numeric data where each element only contains a scalar. MATLAB is optimized for dealing with multi-dimensional numeric arrays so you should convert your data to that format using `cell2mat`.

Once it is a multi-dimensional numeric array, you can use `sum` combined with the second input which specifies the dimension along which to perform the operation.

```
data = cell2mat(old_data);
S = sum(data, 3);
```

If you really need a cell array back, you can use `num2cell` on the result to turn it back into a cell array

```
C = num2cell(S);
```

**Update**

It looks like your initial data is a cell array of *strings*. If that's the case, you can instead use `str2double` convert the cell array of strings to a numeric array

```
data = str2double(old_data);
S = sum(data, 3);
```

Comment: I tried this command before and I got the following error:

Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

Comment: @AshutoshSingla What is inside of each cell? Clearly it's not a scalar like you mentioned